# TPM remote programming with " invalid pointer"

Tags: tpm, tss

I am a beginner about TPM programming. Because of law, I have to use IBM software TPM. I hope I can provide the function of computer A to computer B.
When I want to connect computers between TSS, The TSS on computer A will shut down with `tcsd free() invalid pointer`.

I make sure that I have never used `free()` in my programming. So I suspected that something wrong with TSS.

```
result = Tspi_Context_Create(&hContext);
if (result != TSS_SUCCESS) {
    print_error("Tspi_Context_Create ", result);
    print_error_exit(nameOfFunction, err_string(result));
    exit(result);
}
    //Connect Context
result = Tspi_Context_Connect(hContext,NULL);
if (result != TSS_SUCCESS) {
    print_error("Tspi_Context_Connect", result);
    print_error_exit(nameOfFunction, err_string(result));
    Tspi_Context_FreeMemory(hContext, NULL);  
    Tspi_Context_Close(hContext);
    exit(result);
}

        /* Create TPM NV object */
result = Tspi_Context_CreateObject(hContext, TSS_OBJECT_TYPE_NV, 0,&hNVStore);
if (result != TSS_SUCCESS)
{
    print_error("Tspi_Context_CreateObject", result);
    print_error_exit(nameOfFunction, err_string(result));
    Tspi_Context_FreeMemory(hContext, NULL);
    Tspi_Context_Close(hContext);
    exit(result);
}
```

Comment: Showing which part of the code causes the error would be useful

Comment: `Tspi_Context_FreeMemory()` calls `free()`. Hard to tell what went wrong without all the code.